# How to prevent hadoop from starting in safe mode?

Tags: hadoop

I have a local hadoop cluster and recently after I execute

```
start-dfs.sh && start-yarn.sh
```

it always starts in safe mode. Even if I do `hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave` the next time I restart cluster it again starts in safe mode.

My question is how to return cluster to normal mode, except for formatting   (I do notice that some blocks are corrupted).

**EDIT**

I did:

```
hdfs namenode -format
```

but I'm still having:

```
localhost: nodemanager did not stop gracefully after 5 seconds: killing with kill -9
```

Though, hadoop does not start in safe mode anymore...

Comment: Basically namenode enters in safe mode in unusual situations, for example when disk is full, also in the start-up phase. Did you check your storage?

Comment: There is enough space on the disk

Comment: As per my understanding there is no way to prevent it from starting in safe mode  because the cluster needs to validate all the blocks and their locations before you turn it off once that is validated you can change it.

Comment: @VIN Do you mean formatting hdfs is the only option?